# Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin) in Laravel and Vue Js App

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, cors

developing Laravel 10 + Vue Js 3 application both projects files are separately. I have following api.php login route as well

```
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'submit']);
```

and using following Login in vue.js

```
const handleLogin = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost/api/login', getFormattedCredentials())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            waitingOnVerification.value = true
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
            alert(error.response.data.message)
        })
}
```

but when I try to use log in vue front end it is inspect console encounted following error msg as response

`OPTIONS http://localhost/api/login`

`Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin)`

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/api/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.`

how to fix this problem?

Comment: `how to fix this problem?` - add CORS headers to the response

Comment: do you mean which file frontend or backend?

Comment: *to the response* ... only the "backend" sends a response

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#cors

Answer (score 1):

The error you encountered is related to the CORS policy.
In your case, it seems that you have not configured this policy in your Laravel project.

In Laravel, you can configure the CORS policy by going to the `config\cors.php` file.

This file should look something like this (you can customize it as you need):

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```